# Access VBA not able to update a form's control source after openning this form

Tags: vba, ms-access

In Access I would like to open a closed form before updating a textbox's control source on this form.

I have the following VB codes. But it gets stuck at updating controlsource once the form pops up, giving a runtime error 438. I tried another function on the form to refresh controls right after openning this form and it got stuck as well.

I tried to operate on this form while it was open and it went well. So I believe VB thinks this form is still closed after openning it. Anyone knows how to open a closed form and operate on it in a single `sub`? Thanks

```
 ...
 DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFormName", , , , , acDialog        
 Forms.frmFormName.Text50.ControlSource = "='value'"
 ...
```

Answer (score 3):

```
DoCmd.OpenForm "frmFormName", , , , , acDialog
```

opens the form **modal**. That means, code execution is halted until the form is closed (or set to `Visible=False`).

So the next line is executed when the form is already closed.

You could pass the parameter via `OpenArgs` and set the control source in `Form_Open`, not from the outside.